# Drupal CC/Views - new fields not showing up in CCK

Tags: drupal, view, cck, drupal-fields

I am  working with CCK/Views for the first time, and I am stuck on a detail...

I have created a custom type called Outlet (as in Retail Outlet).
I added 5 new fields to my new custom type.
I created some content in my new Content Type.

Then I went to Views to Add a new "Node" type View for my New Content Type.
I click on Fields to select Fields.

There is a option/select box to select which fields to choose...
But alas, my new Content Type and related fields does not show up here.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

It should be under Content in the dropdown.

It will be called field_whatever_you_named

Comment: gosh. The fields were buried way down on the list! I got caught up on the "Group" selection. 

thank you!